# ajax delete function doesn't call the related action in the controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project. In my project I have an Index view that shows a table of records and near each record there is a 'Delete' button. After user clicks the 'Delete' button I call jQueryAjaxDelete function (which is in site.js) and send Delete action and its controller container to it. Now my problem is when I click the 'Delete' button a confirmation message shows to me but after clicking the button to delete the record, it doesn't call 'Delete' action in Gate controller so it doesn't delete the record. Here is what I have tried:
Index view:

```
<div id="tablecontainer" class="my-5 col-sm-12 p-4">
    <table id="myDummyTable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr id="headerrow">
                
                <th>
                    Desc
                </th>
                <th>
                    Operation
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                       
                      
                        <a onclick="jQueryAjaxDelete('@Url.Action("Delete","Gates",new {id=item.Id},Context.Request.Scheme)','Delete')" class="btn btn-info text-white"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> delete</a>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is Delete action in Gate controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Deleted id:" + id);
    var gate = await _context.Gate.FindAsync(id);
    gate.IsDeleted = true;
    _context.Gate.Update(gate);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    return Json(new { html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_ViewAll", _context.Gate.ToList()) });
}
```

Here is jQueryAjaxDelete in site.js:

```
jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {
   
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?')) {
        
        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.action,
                data: new FormData(form),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    $('#view-all').html(res.html);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log('confirm deleteAjax error');
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex)
        }
    }
```

I appreciate if anyone suggest to me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add `RequestVerificationToken` in the frontend, because you have added `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in the backend.
2. The form itself is a `url`. You can use it directly.
3. You have pass the parameter with querystring. So you can remove the FormData.

Here is the code can call the action.

```
 <!--in .cshtml-->
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 
 @section Scripts{
 <script>
    var jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {
        
        if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?')) {
            console.log(form)
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',

                    url: form,

                    headers: {
                        RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },

                    success: function (res) {
                        $('#view-all').html(res.html);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log('confirm deleteAjax error');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex)
            }
        }
    }
</script>

}
```

If `<a>` reloads or redirects when you click, you could pass an event into `jQueryAjaxDelete` and use this method.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it still has the same problem and doesn't delete the record.

Comment: @hrz, do you have any errors in browser's devtool?

Comment: Yes the errors are as the following:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null
    at site.js?v=ze6Wp9bbDbtE34-3ja2Jdr7w_DolP0VUT1T5YnTYu5o:106          Also it goes into error in try and shows --->    confirm deleteAjax error

Comment: It may prompt some element doesn't exists, you can put `<script src="">` after the body. The `onchange` that you didn't show in the question.

Comment: For the first function I wrote the error is TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
    at jQueryAjaxDelete (site.js?v=MAbRkpRB3gyriSmQSet35p5vN5TwFByvJ46h87m2ccc:57)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1650) in browser devtools and for the second one I omited onchange function  and the errors are :44357/Gates/Delete/3:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
site.js?v=ze6Wp9bbDbtE34-3ja2Jdr7w_DolP0VUT1T5YnTYu5o:95 confirm deleteAjax error
site.js?v=ze6Wp9bbDbtE34-3ja2Jdr7w_DolP0VUT1T5YnTYu5o:96 Object